# Reading a local file a _second_ time using the html5 file reader API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on some small helper utility. The approach is an in-page web app which is typically loaded from the local file system. That all works. Inside that app I need to be able to load and process *local* files (storing and reloading a profile). That works so far, but I have a problem left where I would like to ask for help:

I am using the [filereader.js](http://bgrins.github.io/filereader.js/) wrapper around the html5 file reader API. Things work so far, I am able to select, read and process a file in-page. Great! I even can process several files one after another. However there is one problem where I don't know how to start debugging it: I can *not* read a specific file *a second time*. I can select it, sure, but it is not read, thus not processed. It looks like there are no events generated at all by the file reader API. This *might* be connected to either caching or the prior usage of the file not having been terminated by me correctly, I have no idea.

Here is the relevant code:

My FileReader JS function:

```
function FileReader( selector, options ) {
    var options = $.extend({
        clicked:  function(){},
        payload:  function(){},
        selected: function(){}
    }, options||{} );
    var widget   = convert( selector );
    var selector = widget.find( 'input:file');

    function clicked( event ) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // highlight button as user feedback
        highlight();
        // raise the file selection dialog
        selector.click();
        // signal action to element
        options.clicked();
    }

    function convert( selector ) {
        var widget = $( selector );
        // create new content for widget
        var hotspot = $( '<a class="hotspot">' + widget.html() + '</a>' ).bind( 'click', clicked );
        var selector = $( '<input type="file" style="display:none;" />' );
        // replace initial content of widget
        widget.empty().append( $('<form />').append(selector).append(hotspot) );
        widget.find( 'input:file' ).fileReaderJS( { accept: false,
                                                                                                readAsDefault: 'BinaryString',
                                                                                                on: { load: selected } } );
        return widget;
    }

    function highlight() {
        // flash button by changing the background color for 100 msecs
        widget.css( 'background-color', 'whitesmoke' );
        setTimeout( function(){ widget.css( 'background-color', 'transparent' ); }, 100 );
    }

    function selected( event, file ) {
        // process payload
        options.payload( event.target.result );
        // signal event to controlling element
        options.selected();
    }

    return {}
} // FileReader
```

This method is called with `'#wProfileImport'` as value of the argument `selector`, which actually works and converts the markup below

```
<span id="wProfileImport" class="control button">
    <img src="assets/img/profile-import.png">
</span>
```

such that it contains a (hidden) file input tag which is used to fire the file selection dialog (which works fine):

```
<span id="wProfileImport" class="control button">
    <form>
        <input type="file" style="display:none">
    </form>
    <a class="hotspot">
        <img src="assets/img/profile-import.png">
    </a>
</span>
```

Now when clicking the image the file selector is fired, I can select a *local* file and its content is handed over to the `options.payload` callback. As said all fine and working also for more than a single file one after another. The only problem that remains: being able to read in *the same* file again. No event is fired, no content read, nothing.

So my question is: what do I have to do the process a file *a second time*, if it is selected by the user?

Comment: I think your problem is: user selects file `A.ext`, your JavaScript does some processing. User selects file `A.ext` again and nothing happens. Is this correct?

Comment: @Doge that is exactly my problem, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how the `onchange` event works in JavaScript.

If you have a text input and you type a word, let's say [`"bird"`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WNrx2jq184). You unfocus the field, this will cause the `onchange` event to trigger. If you then go back into the field and change the word, then without unfocussing change it back to `"bird"` and *then* unfocus the `onchange` event will **not** fire because the value didn't change.

Other events like `onkeydown` and `onfocus` will fire however.

See if you can find another event that you can use. Maybe `onclick` or `onfocus`. I do fear that these fire too early.

A workaround to to destroy the `input` once you read the file and render a *new* one in it's place. This way if the user selects the *same* file it will count as an `onchange` again.

Another possibility is to not use the `onchange` event but do the process once you press a submit button. You can get a reference to the file with:

```
var file = document.getElementById("#the_file_input").files[0];
```

Comment: There is no submit button. I could implement one and catch the event, but I prefer your approach to simply create a new and fresh input tag. Sounds pretty straight forward, since I can simply take the details from the one already there... I will give it a try...

Comment: Ok, I had to reorganize a few things, but the general approach _does_ work. This proves that indeed the issue was that the content of the input tag is not changed in case of selecting _the same_ file a second time. So your answer pointed me into the right direction. Thanks!